# UIView factory and delegate

Tags: ios, uiview, delegates

I want to draw a chart in an `UIView`. The question is how do I get the data (Points) to the view. If I create a protocol and set the `UIViewController` as the delegate where in the `UIView` do I call the delegate methods (`initWithFrame`? might be to early, and the delegate might not be set, `awakeFromNib`? but the view is 100%  created in code, it has no nib file) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> initWithFrame? might be to early, and the delegate might not be set.

In fact, the delegate **cannot** be set by the time you're in `initWithFrame:`, since the first thing you do with an object after allocation is initialization, i. e. until the init method returns, you can't call (well, it's idiomatic not to do so, at least) any other methods.

What you have to do is have a `loadData` or `reloadData` method, that the delegate must call explicitly after having set itself as the delegate of your view. I. e., from the view controller, you can call it like this:

```
@implementation ChartViewController

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        chartView = [[ChartView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        chartView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:chartView];
        [chartView reloadData];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then, in your chart drawing view, implement `- reloadData` as follows:

```
- (void)reloadData
{
    // Call the delegate here,
    // then do the drawing
}
```

Comment: Is it a necessary in ChartViewController's init to set chartView.delegate = self? Can we just set it in reloadData?

Comment: @sunkehappy What? What do you want to set in `reloadData`? Those are two different methods of two different classes...

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken that delegate as a UITableView's delegate.

Answer (score 0):

make a protocol but dont call it delegate. call it dataSource :D

anyways, call it when you first need the data .... as late as possible.. NOT in init.. maybe in the setDataSource call.

or when you draw for the first time and see you have no data..

---

look at UITableView to see how he does it and imitate that

Comment: "awakeFromNib"? It's explicitly stated that the view doesn't have a NIB file.

Comment: "where in the UIView do I call the delegate methods (initWithFrame? might be to early, and the delegate might not be set, awakeFromNib?" -- sorry, I didnt read further, edited

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use `UIViewController` instead of a `UIView`. Because your that view has to manage data. Managing data is a UIViewController's job.

Comment: Not always. See UITableView.

Comment: UITableView does not provide data. Its delegate and datasource provide data. I'm a newbie. Can you teach me more? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is exactly the case with OP's drawing view. It does not provide data, but its delegate does. It just draws the provided data.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure it is a good idea to provide data in a view. I just think it's a better idea to provide data in a view controller. What do you think?

Comment: I think Apple's engineers are good enough not to be argued against. (In other words, concepts are just concepts, and they're not obligatory.)

Comment: I'll think about this. Thank you very much! Sorry for my bad English.